# space under bottom navigation bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I dont have much knowledge of Android studio IDE, but i was asked to fix this problem, i thought there was a margin under the navigation bar but i cant identify the problem.

[image]

**Endless CODE**

```
<TextView android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:height="15px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="55dip"
        android:id="@+id/Tab.Title" android:text="@+id/Tab.Title"
        style="@style/Tab.Title" />


    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/BottomBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/tb_background_bottom" android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:weightSum="0"
       >

        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/PreviousBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons_bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_next" android:layout_weight="1">
            </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/NewTabBtn" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/buttons_bottom"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_btn_home" android:layout_weight="1"></ImageButton>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: just put android:layout_marginBottom="put ur size in dp(try 0 dp)" in linear layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I am assuming that either you want to shift the navigation bar to bottom most position or you want to make the background matter view shorter so that the navigation bar is the lowermost element on the screen.

You need to make use of `android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"` for the `linear layout`.

You don't need to necessarily use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` as the margin settings will override those alignments.

We can adjust the margins as per the view requirement. Try different margin values.